# Tablet hover states are getting stuck

Tags: javascript, ipad, hover, touch, tablet

I have a header menu that uses hover states. On hover, the color of the li changes and the child ul opens below.

In order to make this work on touch devices, I also added a 'hover' class to these elements, with this script:

```
$(".isc-primary-nav li.has-children a.nav-link.hoverable").unbind().on("touchstart", function (e) {
    'use strict';
    var li = $(this).parent().parent();
    if (li.hasClass("hover")) {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        window.location = href;
        return true;
    } else {
        li.addClass("hover");
        // close all fourth-level menus
        $("ul.sub-2 li.active").each(function () {
            $(this).find("span").find(".fa-minus").click();
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $(".isc-primary-nav li.has-children").not($(li)).not($(li).parents()).removeClass("hover");
        e.preventDefault();
        // if we are in .sub-1
        if (li.parent().hasClass("sub-1")) {
            var ul = $(li).find("ul:first");
            var leftBox = $(li).parent();
            resizeBoxes(leftBox, ul);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If the item has not been clicked yet, I add the hover class to reproduce the hover state. Then if the item is already "hovered" over, clicking on the link works as normal.

When a user clicks opens a new menu item, the other menu items should close (just as on desktop, where if you hover over a different item, the other menus close). I do that here, by removing the "hover" class from all but the current menu item (and its parents):

```
$(".isc-primary-nav li.has-children").not($(li)).not($(li).parents()).removeClass("hover");
```

However, in certain cases, the hover states remain. This happens when I open a fourth-level menu, which done by clicking a 'plus' icon rather than hovering; I think the reason it happens with the fourth level is because by clicking on the plus icon, I am focusing on the sub-menu, and giving it the hover state. When I then try to open another menu item, the "hover" class is removed, but the when I inspect the elements I see that they have :hover styles.

Why is :hover persisting after I tap elsewhere on the tablet? If I tap around elsewhere on the screen, the :hover state eventually goes away, but it needs to go away as soon as I open another menu item, or else I end up with two menus expanded at once and it looks broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a state issue. The problem as far as I know is that the tablet/iPad saves the state it was in on the last page (i.e. your finger touching the menu) and is still in that state when the next page loads.

I think your best option would be to implement your menu as a clickable one rather than a hover one if you are allowed to do so.

Have a look [here](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/) for a post about hover menus and their drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to prevent the :hover states on touchscreens. I added a new class, "no-hover", which is never used on desktop but gets applied during my touchstart event. I changed the touchstart function I posted above by adding "no-hover" everywhere that I remove the "hover" class:

```
li.addClass("hover").removeClass("no-hover");
$(".isc-primary-nav li.has-children").not($(li)).not($(li).parents()).removeClass("hover").addClass("no-hover");
```

Then in my css, I changed all instances of :hover to

```
:hover:not(.no-hover)
```